# how to make a panel have a scrollbar

Tags: html, css, overflow

[My site](http://spencedesign.netau.net/SNL/SNL.html#page2) is a one page website, and I want to be able to make the panel that you see in this website scroll vertically. I tried using `overflow-y: scroll` but it didn't work. I would greatly appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a scroller-y but because you hide the x-scroll, you cant see it because of positioning issues.

change the min-width of .panel to 85% and not 100%.

Answer (score 0):

In your Css File there is one attribute

```
.panel {
min-width: 100%;
}
```

change this `min-width : 100% to 80%;`